# Align navbar and hamburger to the right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm currently using this snippet for a navbar:

http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/fancy-sidebar-navigation

I've edited some content of the navbar but now I want to align the navbar and the hamburger to the right. I've already tried floats and margins but nothing seems to work.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please share the code that you have already written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code:
http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/Ol10M

You need to remove Bootstrap's `navbar-fixed-top {left:0}` to allow the sidebar to float to the right. I just replaced it with "left:auto" in the first style of the CSS in that snippet.

Then you need to replace all the "left" instances with "right" except for the last css rule for the overlay.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
It helped me a lot!